# Manipulating and Uploading Form File Data using HTML5 Technology

Tags: javascript, forms, html, fileapi

I'm tying to use the HTML5 FileReader and possibly the FileWriter API to manipulate and then upload the manipulated data from a file type input tag.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
  $("#files").change(function(e) {
    var files = e.target.files
    ,   reader = new FileReader()
    ,   i;
    for(i=0; f = files[i]; ++i) {
      f = doSomething(reader.readAsBinaryString(f)); // Manipulate the File
    }
    return true;
  });
 });
```

So how would I go about implementing the doSomething method?  I need to return a FileObject that the form can then submit. Is this currently possible on any of the browsers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your current approach:

You don't need the `FileWriter` API. That cannot be used without the [HTML5 Filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/). What you do need is the `BlobBuilder` API from the [File API: Writer spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/).

Second, the `FileReader` read methods are asynchronous, so you can't pass the result
to `doSomething()` like you're doing. You also need to create a separate reader object for each file.

One thing you could try is to read the file as an `ArrayBuffer`, manipulate its bytes via a JS typed array (`Uint8Array`), create a Blob from that buffer, then send the result to the server. Something like this might work (untested):

```
$(function() {
  $("#files").change(function(e) {
    var files = e.target.files;

    [].forEach.call(files, function(f, i) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        doSomething(this.result);
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    });

    return true;
  });
});

var doSomething = function(arrayBuffer) {
  // Create a unsigned 8-bit view from the underlying data buffer.
  var ui8a = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  for (var i = 0; i < ui8a.length; ++i) {
    // Manipulate each byte. Its underlying arraybuffer will be changed.
    // ui8a[i] = xxx // set byte at offset i to something.
  }

  var bb = new WebKitBlobBuilder(); // Build a blob from the arraybuffer data.
  bb.append(ui8a.buffer);

  upload(bb.getBlob('your/filemimetype'));
};

var upload = function(blob) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };
  xhr.send(blob);
};
```

I'm not sure if you need the mimetype passed into `bb.getBlob()`, but that would
be the content type of the file you're working with. Try it.

Comment: Ah, BlobBuilder, thats what I was missing. If am I trying to use a library like  [Gibberish Aes](https://github.com/mdp/gibberish-aes), which takes a string and encrypts it. Could I use `readAsBinaryString`, upload the encrypted string, then when someone downloads and decrypts it agin, somehow build the file from the binary string?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes. `BlobBuilder.append()` is overloaded to take in a number of types, including a `DOMString`. Then call `bb.getBlob()`. Blob are file-like object (`File` inherits from `Blob'.)